# As a UK Citizen, how do I sell shares on NZX?

Tags: stocks, united-kingdom, new-zealand, international-trading

I'm a UK citizen. Some time ago, I worked for a company based in New Zealand. The company went public on NZX and I ended up with some shares.

I have never been to New Zealand and don't have any bank accounts, etc. outside of the UK. I've looked at some UK based trading platforms/stock brokers, but they don't seem to offer the ability to trade shares listed on NZX.

How would I go about selling these shares? Also, would I be liable to pay tax in NZ?

Comment: How do you hold these shares if not for a broker? As actual paper certificates?

Comment: Do you mean that you had shares in the company _before_ it went public? Or did you have options for stock that you _exercised_ when it went public? Who did you communicate with about that?

Comment: You shouldn't be liable for any tax, as there's no capital gains tax in New Zealand.

Comment: These are "normal" shares allocated when the company went public (not previously held prior to that). I have a "Common Shareholder Number" and "Faster Identification Number".

Comment: did you check if the company offers any trading option or allows to transfer shares ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the UK taxes you on "world income". So even if you don't pay tax in NZ, the uk as a tax resident will be asking for their cut.

Answer (score 0):

Computershare nz has a share selling service for non nz residents.
Buying the shares seems impossible though

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/89127)